# Timeouts vs ExpireTimeSpan UseCookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Me he encontrado en el trabajo una aplicación MVC con las siguientes propiedades y hay algo que me huele mal. No termino de entender los timeouts del `authentication`, `sessionState` y `ExpireTimeSpan`. Es necesario tener los tres? Que diferencias hay entre cada uno? He buscado algo de información pero no logro distinguir sus usos.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/SignOn.aspx" timeout="40" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>

<sessionState timeout="30" />

 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/default.aspx"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = 15
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

El Form authentication timeout establece la cantidad de minutos en minutos que la cookie de autenticación se establece como válida, lo que significa que después de ciertos minutos, la cookie caducará y el usuario ya no estará autenticado; y se le redireccionará a la pagina de inicio de sesión automáticamente. El valor slidingExpiration=true básicamente dice que después de cada solicitud realizada, el temporizador se restablece y, siempre que el usuario haga una solicitud dentro del valor de tiempo de espera, continuará siendo autenticado. Si se configura slidingExpiration=false la cookie de autenticación caducará después de la cierta cantidad de minutos independientemente de si el usuario realiza una solicitud dentro del valor de tiempo de espera o no.

El SessionState timeout establece la cantidad de tiempo que un proveedor de estado de sesión debe almacenar los datos en la memoria (o el almacén de respaldo que se esté usando, SQL Server, OutOfProc, etc.) para una sesión en particular. Por ejemplo, si coloca un objeto en Sesion usando el valor en tu ejemplo, esta información se eliminará después de 30 minutos. El usuario aún puede estar autenticado, pero los datos en la sesión pueden no estar presentes. El valor SessionTimeout siempre se restablece después de cada solicitud.

El ExpireTimeSpan es la opción que le permite establecer por cuánto tiempo es válida la cookie emitida.  Si SlidingExpiration se establece en true entonces, la cookie se volverá a emitir en cualquier solicitud a la mitad del ExpireTimeSpan.

Fuentes:
http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

Comment: muy buena respuesta hermano :D

Comment: Hermana* soy una chica, y gracias!

Comment: ¡Ok hermanita! muchas gracias por la respuesta :D está bien detallada

Comment: Por lo tanto el ExpireTimeSpan  y Form authentication timeout es lo mismo no?

Comment: Si, funcionan igual